# How do I manage and protect my Streaming Locators from Azure Media Services?

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-media-services

Background:
I have an Azure Media Service setup with a video uploaded and encoded. To access this video I've created a Streaming Locator in Azure Portal. With this Locator I can stream the video.

Problem:
How do I make it so that only *my* website can stream that video? I don't want other website to take my Locator and use it in their players because that would mean I'm paying for their streaming traffic.

Is DRM the solution to this problem or do I need to create Locators on-demand when a user firsts clicks on a video and then delete it afterwards?

I've looked into API authentication but that requires a Client Secret which might be problematic on an Angular website. Orr user authentication which is odd to require just for browsing videos.

Answer (score 0):

Thye typical workflow for this would be to use just Clear Key AES content protection and not try to use DRM which has a lot of issues in setting up and getting players to work correctly.  Clear Key still has its player support issues on iOS for example, but it is the easiest way to pull off what you are trying to do.

The workflow would be to set up content protection for the asset and use AES Clear Key on the Streaming Locators.  Your audience would have to login and authenticate on your web site, which would provide them with a JWT token to play back and decrypt the media.

I dont have a complete example, but this sample in the Javscript SDK shows how to enable clear key encryption and use a JWT token.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Streaming/StreamFileWithAESClearKey/index.ts

Note that it does not cover where you get the JWT token from exactly - it is using a sample token really.  You would have to set up a service (Azure function) that does the authentication of the user and provides them with a valid JWT token for playback. That's left up to you, as there are lots of security layers that have to be considered which would be too complicated for sample code.

To use AES Clear Key you follow these steps:

1. Create a ContentKeyPolicy with the claims you want to use in the token.  That can be issuer, audience, etc.  You set the primary verification key on this policy and the restriction type is set to token type of JWT
2. When you want to publish a video, you create a new Streaming Locator for it and set the "DefaultContentKeyPolicy" on the streaming locator to point the the name of the ContentKeyPolicy you created in step 1.

Then on the client side, when a customer logs into your site or selects a video - you can create the JWT token for that user and pass it into the player.  This is demonstrated in the sample above.

There is also a .NET C# version of that same sample flow up here if you prefer:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/tree/main/ContentProtection/BasicAESClearKey